# How to fix compile error when compiling the i2S module

Tags: raspbian

I tried to integrate I2S audio module following the instruction stated on the article “GitHub - nejohnson2/rpi-i2s: Using the ICS43432 MEMS microphone on a Raspberry Pi with i2s”. An error message was reported as bellow.

```
"include/config/auto.conf: No file nor directory founded"
```

I appreciate it if someone can advise me how to fix this error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd rpi-i2s-audio
pi@raspberrypi:~/rpi-i2s-audio $ make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r )/build M=$(pwd) modules

make: directory '/home/pi/linux-4f2a4cc501c428c940549f39d5562e60404ac4f7'　move into directory
Makefile:590: **include/config/auto.conf: No file nor directory founded**

  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
```

The Raspbian version is as below:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi@raspberrypi:~ $  uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.113-v7+ #1300 SMP Thu Mar 26 16:53:09 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```